# How to optimize my query speed (avoid using subselect for every row)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I have a table called CisLinkLoadedData. Is has `Distributor`, `Network`, `Product`, `DocumentDate`, `Weight`, `AmountCP` and `Quantity` columns. It used to store some product daily sales. `AmountCP / Quantity` is the **price** for the product at certain date. There are **promo** and **regular** sales, but no flag for it. We can tell if certain record is **regular** or **promo** by comparing it's **price** with the **maximum recorded price** within month. I did explained it on this picture.
[image]

I need to make a query to display summarized regular and promo sales of certain product per month. Well, I made it, but it very slow (6 minutes to execute at 1.6 millions records).
I suspect this is because I use subquery to determine max price for every record, but I don't know how to make it another way.

This is what I made:

```
SELECT
    Distributor,
    Network,
    Product,
    cast(month(DocumentDate) as VARCHAR) + '.' + cast(year(DocumentDate) as VARCHAR) AS MonthYear,
    SUM(Weight) AS MonthlyWeight,
    IsPromo
FROM (SELECT
        main_clld.Distributor,
        main_clld.Network,
        main_clld.Product,
        main_clld.DocumentDate,
        main_clld.Weight,
        main_clld.Quantity,
        main_clld.AmountCP,
        CASE WHEN (main_clld.AmountCP / main_clld.Quantity) < (SELECT MAX(sub_clld.AmountCP / NULLIF(sub_clld.Quantity, 0)) FROM CisLinkLoadedData AS sub_clld WHERE sub_clld.Distributor = main_clld.Distributor AND sub_clld.Network = main_clld.Network AND sub_clld.Product = main_clld.Product AND cast(month(sub_clld.DocumentDate) as VARCHAR) + '.' + cast(year(sub_clld.DocumentDate) as VARCHAR) = cast(month(main_clld.DocumentDate) as VARCHAR) + '.' + cast(year(main_clld.DocumentDate) as VARCHAR) AND sub_clld.Quantity > 0 AND sub_clld.GCRecord IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsPromo
    FROM CisLinkLoadedData AS main_clld
    WHERE main_clld.Quantity > 0 AND main_clld.GCRecord IS NULL) AS bad_query
GROUP BY
    Distributor,
    Network,
    Product,
    cast(month(DocumentDate) as VARCHAR) + '.' + cast(year(DocumentDate) as VARCHAR),
    IsPromo;
```

What is possible to do in such case? By the way, if you can do result table with another structure like that (`Distributor`, `Network`, `Product`, `MonthYear`, `RegularWeight`, `PromoWeight`) - it's even better. This is what I tried initially, but failed.
I use Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: I suspect [Windowed Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) will help, something like: `MAX(main_clld.AmountCP / NULLIF(main_clld.Quantity, 0)) OVER(PARTITION BY main_clld.Distributor, main_clld.Network, main_clld.Product, EOMONTH(main_clld.DocumentDate))`.

Comment: @GarethD - Sorry, I don't understand the use of EOMONTH there. I read the documentation. It returns the last day of the month. How the last day is used there?

Comment: In your query you seem to be limiting the check to only sales within that month (`cast(month(DocumentDate) as VARCHAR) + '.' + cast(year(DocumentDate) as VARCHAR)`) - that is basically what I am using `EOMONTH` for. While there is no real significance of the last day of each month, `EOMONTH` will return the same value for every single day in the month (i.e. 1st June returns the same as 7th June which returns the same as 25th June), so that provides the basis for the grouping. It basically does the same as what you were already doing, but without costly varchar conversion

Comment: You could just as easily use two arguments - `MONTH(DocumentDate), YEAR(DocumentDate)` for the grouping, but in order to reduce amount of text and the function calls I opted for EOMONTH. As an aside: [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: @GarethD - Thank you. This is very cool. The query executed in 16 seconds now, however I still need to compare the result through!

Comment: @Ahmed - No. It can have many prices, but only the **highest** is **regular**. For example: 99, 89, 79, **150**, 95. **150** there is **regular** price. All other prices are **promo**.

Comment: @GarethD - The results are almost same (different sums when network is NULL, but this is invalid anyway). This is good. Make it as answer, so I can accept it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than a correlated subquery, you could use a [windowed function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to retrieve the maximum price per group (each group is defined by the partition by clause):

```
MAX(main_clld.AmountCP / NULLIF(main_clld.Quantity, 0)) 
 OVER(PARTITION BY main_clld.Distributor, main_clld.Network, 
                   main_clld.Product, EOMONTH(main_clld.DocumentDate))
```

I think your full query would end up something like:

```
SELECT
    Distributor,
    Network,
    Product,
    MonthYear,
    SUM(Weight) AS MonthlyWeight,
    IsPromo
FROM (SELECT
        main_clld.Distributor,
        main_clld.Network,
        main_clld.Product,
        main_clld.DocumentDate,
        main_clld.Weight,
        main_clld.Quantity,
        main_clld.AmountCP,
        CAST(MONTH(DocumentDate) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '.' + cast(year(DocumentDate) as VARCHAR(2)) AS MonthYear,
        CASE WHEN (main_clld.AmountCP / main_clld.Quantity) < MAX(main_clld.AmountCP / NULLIF(main_clld.Quantity, 0)) 
                                                                OVER(PARTITION BY main_clld.Distributor, main_clld.Network,
                                                                                    main_clld.Product, EOMONTH(main_clld.DocumentDate)) 
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsPromo
    FROM CisLinkLoadedData AS main_clld
    WHERE main_clld.Quantity > 0 
    AND main_clld.GCRecord IS NULL
    ) AS bad_query
GROUP BY
    Distributor,
    Network,
    Product,
    MonthYear,
    IsPromo;
```